# Run Django API that has 1 hour to execution time

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, celery

I have an API that takes one hour to complete...I am trying to implement celery and run 2 times a day..So what is the best way to run an API asynchronously?

Comment: Check out asyncio

Comment: BTW APIs don't run. They are just descriptions of how to communicate with a service.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already looking at Celery, then Celery Beat is it's scheduler. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

This will allow you to define your '*API*' as a task and easily add rules for its execution at regular intervals, (i.e. twice per day).

A decent higher level tutorial in relation to Django can be found [HERE](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-celery-periodic-tasks/)